# 'Menu Item' in Module's XML file

Tags: joomla-3.4, xml, module-params

In module development, I'm using a field for menu item (from these docs https://docs.joomla.org/Menuitem_form_field_type). I can work out to to show the menu item in the XML:

```
<field name="menuitem1" type="menuitem" default="45" label="Select a menu item" description="Select a menu item" />
```

I can then echo this for the frontend:

```
<a href="<?php echo $params->get('menuitem1');?>" >
```

But this only shows the ID of that menu item, how can I set it to be the actual URI for the menu item selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the URL using the following:

```
$itemid = $params->get('menuitem1', 0);

$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
$link = $menu->getItem($itemid)->link;

echo JRoute::_($link);
```

`$link` will provide you with a non-SEF URL, then as shown above, you can use `JRoute` to convert it to a SEF URL.

Hope this helps

Comment: You're welcome :)... I was just going to say, there shouldn't be an error :)

Comment: Oddly, there's an error shown when linking to the same page - but only a 'Notice' - gone after clearing the cache.